# The image div on the right side doesn't appear

Tags: html, css

I have two side divs containing same image repeating vertically.
They are labeled as: ".left" and ".right".
The left side div ".left" looks fine but ".right" doesn't appear even though I have the same code for both sides.
I need the same image to repeat-vertically for both sides no matter how long the content is.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body{
  margin: 0;

}
.left{
  width: 10%;
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
  height:100%;
  position:fixed;    
  background:transparent url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e1/Blue_crocheting_thread.jpg/40px-Blue_crocheting_thread.jpg") repeat-y scroll 0% 0%;  
  }


.right{
  width: 10%;
  float: right;
  overflow: auto;
  height:100%;
  position:fixed;    
  background:transparent url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e1/Blue_crocheting_thread.jpg/40px-Blue_crocheting_thread.jpg") repeat-y scroll 0% 0%;  
  }

.center
{
  border-top: solid;
  border-bottom: solid;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 950px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  padding: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul li
{
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--Comment-->
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>xxx xxxxxxx | Portofolio</title>

   <!--
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caveat|Open+Sans:400,400i,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">-->

</head>

<!--body-->
<body>
<!--left side picture-->
<div class="left">

</div>
<!--right side picture-->
<div class="right">

</div>
<!--Intro-->
<header class="center">
  <div>
     <img src="pic_trulli.jpg" alt="Italian  Trulli">
     <div>
        <h1>
           xxx xxxxx
        </h1>
        <h2>Web Developer + Educator</h2>
       </div>
    </div>
</header>

<!--main-->
<main>
<!--About Me-->
   <section class="aboutMe">
      <div class="center">
         <h2>
            About Me
         </h2>
         <div>
         <p>
            I'm self-taught, professional web developer and designer.
            I've been in the playground for more than 4 years meeting the best professionals in this industry, researching the excellence in web art and achieving greatest customer satisfaction.
          </p>
          </div>
       <div>
          <a href="#">link</a><br>
          <a href="#">link</a> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

<!--Skills-->
<section class="skills">
<div class="center">
   <h2>
   Skills
   </h2>
   <div>
     <p>
       HTML, CSS, JavaScript
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!--Projects-->
<section class="projects">
   <div class="center">
      <h2>
         Projects
      </h2>
      <div>
         <p>
            Websites:
         </p>
       </div>
       <div>
          <div>
             <img src="pic_trulli.jpg" alt="Italian Trulli">
          </div>
          <a href="#">
             Restaurant
          </a>
        </div>

        <div>
           <div>
              <img src="pic_trulli.jpg" alt="Italian Trulli">
            </div>
            <a href="#">
               Tours
             </a>
          </div>
       </div>

</section>
</main>

<!--footer-->
<footer>

  <div class="center">
            <h2>Let's Keep in Touch!</h2>

            <!-- Social media and contact links. Add or remove any networks. -->
            <div class="contact-info">
                <a href="mailto:greenbluemoonlight@gmail.com">greenbluemoonlight@gmail.com</a><br>
                <a href="tel:1-818-888-8888">xxx-xxx-xxxx</a><br>
                <a href="http://yourwebsite.com">yourwebsite.com</a><br>
                <a href="#">Twitter</a>
                <a href="#">LinkedIn</a>
                <a href="#">Facebook</a>
            </div>

            <p>Copyright 2018 by xxx xxxxx</p>
        </div>

</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove float and need to give left and right position with giving width:40px

```
.left{
  width: 40px;
  left: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  height:100%;
  position:fixed;    
  background:transparent url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e1/Blue_crocheting_thread.jpg/40px-Blue_crocheting_thread.jpg") repeat-y scroll 0% 0%;  
  }


.right{
  width: 40px;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  height:100%;
  position:fixed;    
  background:transparent url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e1/Blue_crocheting_thread.jpg/40px-Blue_crocheting_thread.jpg") repeat-y scroll 0% 0%;  
  }
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body{
  margin: 0;

}
.left{
  width: 40px;
  left: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  height:100%;
  position:fixed;    
  background:transparent url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e1/Blue_crocheting_thread.jpg/40px-Blue_crocheting_thread.jpg") repeat-y scroll 0% 0%;  
  }


.right{
  width: 40px;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  height:100%;
  position:fixed;    
  background:transparent url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e1/Blue_crocheting_thread.jpg/40px-Blue_crocheting_thread.jpg") repeat-y scroll 0% 0%;  
  }

.center
{
  border-top: solid;
  border-bottom: solid;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 950px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  padding: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul li
{
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<!--left side picture-->
<div class="left">

</div>
<!--right side picture-->
<div class="right">

</div>
<!--Intro-->
<header class="center">
  <div>
     <img src="pic_trulli.jpg" alt="Italian  Trulli">
     <div>
        <h1>
           xxx xxxxx
        </h1>
        <h2>Web Developer + Educator</h2>
       </div>
    </div>
</header>

<!--main-->
<main>
<!--About Me-->
   <section class="aboutMe">
      <div class="center">
         <h2>
            About Me
         </h2>
         <div>
         <p>
            I'm self-taught, professional web developer and designer.
            I've been in the playground for more than 4 years meeting the best professionals in this industry, researching the excellence in web art and achieving greatest customer satisfaction.
          </p>
          </div>
       <div>
          <a href="#">link</a><br>
          <a href="#">link</a> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

<!--Skills-->
<section class="skills">
<div class="center">
   <h2>
   Skills
   </h2>
   <div>
     <p>
       HTML, CSS, JavaScript
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!--Projects-->
<section class="projects">
   <div class="center">
      <h2>
         Projects
      </h2>
      <div>
         <p>
            Websites:
         </p>
       </div>
       <div>
          <div>
             <img src="pic_trulli.jpg" alt="Italian Trulli">
          </div>
          <a href="#">
             Restaurant
          </a>
        </div>

        <div>
           <div>
              <img src="pic_trulli.jpg" alt="Italian Trulli">
            </div>
            <a href="#">
               Tours
             </a>
          </div>
       </div>

</section>
</main>

<!--footer-->
<footer>

  <div class="center">
            <h2>Let's Keep in Touch!</h2>

            <!-- Social media and contact links. Add or remove any networks. -->
            <div class="contact-info">
                <a href="mailto:greenbluemoonlight@gmail.com">greenbluemoonlight@gmail.com</a><br>
                <a href="tel:1-818-888-8888">xxx-xxx-xxxx</a><br>
                <a href="http://yourwebsite.com">yourwebsite.com</a><br>
                <a href="#">Twitter</a>
                <a href="#">LinkedIn</a>
                <a href="#">Facebook</a>
            </div>

            <p>Copyright 2018 by xxx xxxxx</p>
        </div>

</footer>
```

Comment: It works ! my right side appears.. but there is a problem. I see extra white space at the right side of image of the right section. It seems like it's not totally " right: 0;"

Comment: it's right:0 is perfect, you can view in snippet,there is not white-space.....Please Check

Comment: yes in here looks perfect..but it looks terrible in jsfiddle..Anyways, thanks a lot

Comment: u. r amazing.. Thanks a lot

Comment: @user27691 Welcome Mate

Answer (score 0):

add `width:40px` and `right:0` to **.right** clsss. and **.left** class. both class has position fixed so instead of `float` you need to set `right:0;` and `left:0;`

```
.right {
    width: 40px;/*changed 10% to 40px*/
    float: right;
    overflow: auto;
    right: 0;/*Newly added*/
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background: transparent url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e1/Blue_crocheting_thread.jpg/40px-Blue_crocheting_thread.jpg) repeat-y scroll 0% 0%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body{  margin: 0; }
.left{
  width: 45px;
  overflow: auto;
  height:100%;
  position:fixed;    
  background:transparent url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e1/Blue_crocheting_thread.jpg/40px-Blue_crocheting_thread.jpg") repeat-y scroll 0% 0%;  
  }
.right{
  width: 45px;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  height:100%;
  position:fixed;    
  background:transparent url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e1/Blue_crocheting_thread.jpg/40px-Blue_crocheting_thread.jpg");  
  }
.center{
  border-top: solid;
  border-bottom: solid;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 950px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  padding: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul li
{
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">

</div>
<!--right side picture-->
<div class="right">

</div>
<!--Intro-->
<header class="center">
  <div>
     <img src="pic_trulli.jpg" alt="Italian  Trulli">
     <div>
        <h1>
           xxx xxxxx
        </h1>
        <h2>Web Developer + Educator</h2>
       </div>
    </div>
</header>

<!--main-->
<main>
<!--About Me-->
   <section class="aboutMe">
      <div class="center">
         <h2>
            About Me
         </h2>
         <div>
         <p>
            I'm self-taught, professional web developer and designer.
            I've been in the playground for more than 4 years meeting the best professionals in this industry, researching the excellence in web art and achieving greatest customer satisfaction.
          </p>
          </div>
       <div>
          <a href="#">link</a><br>
          <a href="#">link</a> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

<!--Skills-->
<section class="skills">
<div class="center">
   <h2>
   Skills
   </h2>
   <div>
     <p>
       HTML, CSS, JavaScript
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!--Projects-->
<section class="projects">
   <div class="center">
      <h2>
         Projects
      </h2>
      <div>
         <p>
            Websites:
         </p>
       </div>
       <div>
          <div>
             <img src="pic_trulli.jpg" alt="Italian Trulli">
          </div>
          <a href="#">
             Restaurant
          </a>
        </div>

        <div>
           <div>
              <img src="pic_trulli.jpg" alt="Italian Trulli">
            </div>
            <a href="#">
               Tours
             </a>
          </div>
       </div>

</section>
</main>

<!--footer-->
<footer>

  <div class="center">
            <h2>Let's Keep in Touch!</h2>

            <!-- Social media and contact links. Add or remove any networks. -->
            <div class="contact-info">
                <a href="mailto:greenbluemoonlight@gmail.com">greenbluemoonlight@gmail.com</a><br>
                <a href="tel:1-818-888-8888">xxx-xxx-xxxx</a><br>
                <a href="http://yourwebsite.com">yourwebsite.com</a><br>
                <a href="#">Twitter</a>
                <a href="#">LinkedIn</a>
                <a href="#">Facebook</a>
            </div>

            <p>Copyright 2018 by xxx xxxxx</p>
        </div>

</footer>
```